# Bouncing an image in a polygonal way with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hey guys am new to pygame .I have to make a ball image `ball.jpg` to bounce in polygonal way.I have also an another ball image which is running in a square way.What i need is to add an another ball image and bounce it in a polygonal way. My code is

```
import pygame
from itertools import cycle
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300)) 
s_r = screen.get_rect()
ball = pygame.image.load('ball.jpg')
player = pygame.Rect((100, 100, 50, 50))
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 5
up, down, left, right = (0, -speed), (0, speed), (-speed, 0), (speed, 0)

dirs = cycle([up, right, down, left])
dir = next(dirs)

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        raise

# move player
player.move_ip(dir)
# if it's outside the screen
if not s_r.contains(player):
    # put it back inside
    player.clamp_ip(s_r)
    # and switch to next direction
    dir = next(dirs)

screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
screen.blit(ball,player)

pygame.display.flip()
timer.tick(25)
```

This code works perfectly with one image ..What i need is to add an another image and it must run in polygonal shape on pygame window..

Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks

Comment: How should this polygonal way look like?

Comment: @sloth you helped me in moving the image in square manner ..i need the other image to rotate like in a polygonal way

Comment: @sloth the polygonal way is described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=966UK-CrmIQ. when i added polgonal1.move_ip(dir) it didnt works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some vector math to do this.

Create a list of points that describe the path the object should move, then calculate a vector describing the direction from the current position to the target position. Then move the object by using that vector. Once you hit your target, aim for the next point to move.

Here's an example:

```
import pygame
import math
from itertools import cycle

# some simple vector helper functions, stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114962/142637
def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [ u[i]+v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]

def sub(u, v):
    return [ u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]    

def dot(u, v):
    return sum(u[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(u)))

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.x, self.y = (0, 0)
        self.speed = 2.5
        self.color = (200, 200, 200)
        self.path = cycle(path)
        self.set_target(next(self.path))

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    # for drawing, we need the position as tuple of ints
    # so lets create a helper property
    @property
    def int_pos(self):
        return map(int, self.pos)

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self.t_x, self.t_y

    @property
    def int_target(self):
        return map(int, self.target)   

    def next_target(self):
        self.set_target(self.pos)
        self.set_target(next(self.path))

    def set_target(self, pos):
        self.t_x, self.t_y = pos

    def update(self):
        # if we won't move, don't calculate new vectors
        if self.int_pos == self.int_target:
            return self.next_target()

        target_vector = sub(self.target, self.pos) 

        # a threshold to stop moving if the distance is to small.
        # it prevents a 'flickering' between two points
        if magnitude(target_vector) < 2: 
            return self.next_target()

        # apply the balls's speed to the vector
        move_vector = [c * self.speed for c in normalize(target_vector)]

        # update position
        self.x, self.y = add(self.pos, move_vector)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.int_pos, 4)

pygame.init()
quit = False

path = [(26, 43),
        (105, 110),
        (45, 225),
        (145, 295),
        (266, 211),
        (178, 134),
        (250, 56),
        (147, 12)]

path2 = [(26, 43),
         (105, 10),
         (45, 125),
         (150, 134),
         (150, 26),
         (107, 12)]

ball = Ball(path)
ball.speed = 1.9

ball2 = Ball(path2)
ball2.color = (200, 200, 0)

balls = [ball, ball2]

while not quit:
    quit = pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT)
    pygame.event.poll()

    map(Ball.update, balls)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    map(Ball.draw, balls)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image]

---

Here's an example without a custom class:

```
import pygame
import math
from itertools import cycle

# some simple vector helper functions, stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114962/142637
def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def sub(u, v):
    return [ u[i]-v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]    

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

pygame.init()
quit = False

path = [(26, 43),
        (105, 110),
        (45, 225),
        (145, 295),
        (266, 211),
        (178, 134),
        (250, 56),
        (147, 12)]
path = cycle(path)         
target = next(path)
ball = pygame.rect.Rect(target[0], target[1], 10, 10)
speed = 3.6

while not quit:
    quit = pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT)
    pygame.event.poll()

    if ball.topleft == target:
        target = next(path)

    target_vector = sub(target, ball.topleft) 

    if magnitude(target_vector) < 2: 
        target = next(path)
    else:
        move_vector = [c * speed for c in normalize(target_vector)]
        ball.move_ip(move_vector)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('Grey'), ball)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: ..this is what exactly i wanted ..:D

Comment: ..since am not in math ..its very difficult to do this ..:D ..thanx for the help anyways

Comment: ..but how can i add my image file instead of that balls which we have create..i have tried replacing pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.int_pos, 4) to screen.blit(ball) ..but it didnt worked..

Comment: @user3792941 should be `screen.blit(ball, self.int_pos)`. make sure you loaded the image into a variable named `ball`.

Comment: but how can i load an image into varibale with class ..is it like self.ball = pygame.image.load()..and on which function ??

Comment: @user3792941 Yes. You can use `self.img = pygame.image.load('path_to_image')` in the `__init__` function, then use `screen.blit(self.img, self.int_pos)` in the `draw` function.

Comment: ..this one helped ..but i still have a doubt when i gone through the code..where have you defined self.pos ?

Comment: It's a property that calls the function `pos()`, defined as `@property def pos(self):`

Comment: thanx ..but i still have a doubt .in the last part you have shown me to move the image in squarely manner with some single pieces of code ..but you have used classes here ...can we do like polgonobject.move_ip(dir) as like of the last question ?

Comment: ..you are just an experts so its really easy to understand it for you ..am just a beginner in pygame so for me its bit hard to understand the code in classes ..do you know how to rotate the image in polygonal way without classes..Just like you did in last answer :)

Comment: I added an example without classes

Comment: thanks for the help.now it makes some sence for me ..:D

Comment: ..in the edit you gave me loads only 1 image ..but i want to load the two images

Comment: it would be really helpful if you edit the updated code for the functioning of two images

Comment: ..do i need to ask a new question or can you help me with this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523607/start-event-when-button-is-clicked-with-pygame ..please have a look at this